# Remove facebook pixel error "Invalid Match Key Parameters for ViewContent Event"

Tags: shopify, facebook-pixel

My developer has integrated facebook pixel on my shopify site. But after 3 days it is showing me this error in diagnostic window. I am trying to resolve this at my end.

```
You’re sending the same event ID for many instances of your ViewContent events. Event IDs are unique identifiers that are used to deduplicate identical events received from your pixel and the Conversions API so they’re not counted twice. To ensure that Facebook is accurately counting your events, each unique event instance needs its own unique event ID.
This may cause issues with the measurement of your events and the attribution of your ad campaigns.
```

So to remove this I simple enabled "external_id" parametre from "Automatic Advanced matching" option but I am not quite sure that I did right thing or not as I am new in integrating this. After solving this, I am seeing this error now as mentioned in screenshot
[image: Describing error on facebook diagnostic window]

Is there something in code, that I need to change to resolve this issue.

**Note: Setup is made through a partner integration.**

Please help me to resolve these errors. If you need more info, please let me know.
Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried both the option

Switching OFF "Automatic advanced matching"

Switching ON "Automatic advanced matching" -> Show options (External ID --> ON)

Finally I observed we have to go with option 1. Still the issue will come single time for each conversion event. After first time we encounter the error we have to move it to ignore list. For each event we will get error we have to do similar trick. Once all event encountered such error and all ignored problem might be solved.

So far I have done for 4 events which I got error. After that I have not got the error for those 4 events. Waiting for my other 2 events error.

But not sure the problem is solved permanently but not seeing any problem for those 4 events for 48 hours. But definitely shopify and facebook together need to solve. But both passing ball to one another.

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you please let me know the events for which you have tested? and i think you are not seeing problem because you have added in ignore list now.